# How do I set DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom parameter on a DataTable column?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have one image column and two text columns.
I used to populate `DataGridView` indirectly, but then I needed filtering so I switched to using `DataTable` as `DataSource` parameter of my `DataGridView`. This enabled me to use the `RowFilter`.

This is how I added an image column to the `DataTable`:

```
dataTable.Columns.Add("Image", typeof(byte[]));
```

and I added a few rows with images:

```
var row = dataTable.NewRow();
row["Image"] = imageData;
```

But the images are too large and they need to fit. With the `DataGridViewImageColumn`, I used to do this:

```
ImgColumn.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom;
```

But with the `DataTable`'s `byte[]` column I don't see how I can do this.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can accomplish this? Thank you.

Comment: Why dont you use typeof(Image)? Just wonder.

Comment: @onur Because I'm receiving images as byte[] from RestClient.DownloadData(), and there's no point in creating MemoryStream and casting them to Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I didn't know you can still access DGV columns:

```
((DataGridViewImageColumn)Dgv.Columns[ImageColumnIndex]).ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom;
```